# Logging an invalid login

Tags: asp.net, logging, authentication

Using the Login control in ASP.NET...

The Login.Authenticate event is used to authenticate the credentials.
The Login.LoginError event is called when there are invalid credentials.

There is an appSetting to toggle the logging invalid logins.

Any preference as to where to do that logging?  In Authenticate, where credentials are checked, or LoginError, where you know the credentials are invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LoginError event is raised when the credentials entered by the user are invalid.

So it's best to log in LoginError.